# Using all 4 RAM Slots

Tags: memory, motherboard

I am running on an Intel DX58SO with i7 processor.
The computer guy who supplied the system said that only three out of four memory slots should be used for optimal performance.

Is this true? I want to take advantage of the fourth channel, but his advice is bugging me.

Thank you for any insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on this review [Hardware Secrets Review](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/Intel-DX58SO-Smackover-Motherboard/643/3) , this motherboard uses Triple-Channel technology, which means that it can use three ram sticks optimally. While you can certainly add a fourth, it would decrease performance for the memory space above the block created by the first three.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the link! That cleared the concern I had. Now I am going to replace the three 1 GB modules with 2 GB modules instead of adding to the extra channel.